# Can't assign domain to Angular project on specific port with Nginx on ubuntu

Tags: angular, ubuntu, nginx, dns

I have an Angular project that's using the port 4201.  I built the project and configured nginx to deploy it.

When I access my server with the IP Address, and the specified port, everything works.

I would like to assign my domain name to this project, and I followed lots of tutorials, but it always shows the "Welcome to Nginx" page...

I'm lost.

Here is the configuration I put in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled :

```
server {
        listen 4201;
        listen [::]:4201;
        root /var/www/html/alienprods;
        index index.html index.htm;
   server_name alienprods.com www.alienprods.com

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
}
```

Do you have any idea ? Am I forgetting something ?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Check your `index.html` file on `/var/www/html/alienprods` to confirm that it's not the default provided by nginx.

Comment: @penleychan I checked and it's not the default one. It really is the one from my app. As I said, if I try to access my website from the IP address, with the port (e.g : 111.222.333.444:4201) everything works. I'd like to know how to access the same ip:port, but through the domain "alienprods.com"

Comment: Oh, I see... That's because if you want to do without port by default you need to use port 80. Otherwise you would need to setup some kind of reverse proxy if you want to continue to use port 4201

Comment: @penleychan oh okay, i'm gonna go check the reverse proxy configuration. Maybe I forgot to do that ! Thanks !

Comment: @penleychan okay so... i tried different things. Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my issue. I didn't understand nginx well enough.

Here is my alienprods.conf file now :

```
server {
        listen 4201;
        listen [::]:4201;
        root /var/www/html/alienprods;
        index index.html index.htm;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name alienprods.com www.alienprods.com;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://*MY_IP_ADDRESS*:4201;
   }
}
```